# Command that works in terminal doesn't work with go exec.Command

Tags: go, exec, go-ethereum, geth

I'm trying to attach to a go-ethereum node from a go script:

```
accountInfo:= fmt.Sprintf("attach %v --exec 'eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])'", connect)
    //x, err := exec.Command("geth", accountInfo).Output() // returns 'Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: no known transport for URL scheme "c"'
    x, err := exec.Command("geth", accountInfo).Output() // returns "invalid command: "attach ws://127.0.0.1:8101...." <--- rest of the metaData string

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

This command works perfectly fine in terminal but it keeps telling me it's invalid when running it like this. This is making me go nuts.

Comment: You are passing the arguments to geth as a single argument, because you bypassed the shell processing. Either exec a shell that runs geth, or pass the arguments in a string slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`os/exec` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/):

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions, pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells.

Since the `arg ...string` parameter of `exec.Command()` isn't processed by a shell, each argument is handed to the command exactly as specified. In your case, the entire content of `metaData` is provided to `geth` as a single argument.

You should instead create a slice of strings, each containing a single argument. And then provide that slice as the `arg` parameter using the  `...` notation.

Here's an example demonstrating this, using the `uname` command:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    command := "uname"
    argsString := "--kernel-name --machine"
    argsSlice := []string{"--kernel-name", "--machine"}

    // Equivalent command:
    // $ uname "--kernel-name --machine"
    fmt.Println("exec.Command(command, argsString)")
    stringOutput, err := exec.Command(command, argsString).CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed: %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Output:\n%s\n", stringOutput)

    // Equivalent command:
    // $ uname --kernel-name --machine
    fmt.Println("exec.Command(command, argsSlice)")
    sliceOutput, err := exec.Command(command, argsSlice...).CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Output:\n%s\n", sliceOutput)
}
```

And it's otuput:

```
$ go run main.go
exec.Command(command, argsString)
Failed: exit status 1
Output:
uname: unrecognized option '--kernel-name --machine'
Try 'uname --help' for more information.

exec.Command(command, argsSlice)
Output:
Linux x86_64
```